# I want to fetch final result of while Loop in SQL using SQL SERVER (refer the code)

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I have written this code and no I want to fetch the final value of @statusCount. Any guidance on what would be next line of code?

```
declare @counterID int, @totalCOunt int, @EntityID int, @statusCOunt int, @flag int 


set @totalCOunt = (select Count(EntityID) as COunt from 
                        (select distinct EntityID, max(IntervalEnddate) as  IntervalENddate
                        from PrintEntity PE 
                        where PE.Status<>0 
                        and PE.EntityType=15 
                        and Isnull(PE.OverallStatus ,0) > 0 
                        and PE.EntityID in (select distinct SO.ID 
                        from StrategicObjective SO where SO.status <>0 and SO.CompanyID=3186) Group By EntityID) SO)

set @counterID=0

while (@counterID <= @totalCOunt)
BEGIN
        set @entityID=(select EntityID from 
                        (select distinct EntityID, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY EntityID) AS RowNum, max(IntervalEnddate) as  IntervalENddate
                        from PrintEntity PE 
                        where PE.Status<>0 
                        and PE.EntityType=15 
                        and Isnull(PE.OverallStatus ,0) > 0 
                        and PE.EntityID in (select distinct SO.ID 
                        from StrategicObjective SO where SO.status <>0 and SO.CompanyID=3186) Group By EntityID) SO where RowNum=(@counterID+1))

        set @flag = (select Count(EntityID) from 
                         PrintEntity PE 
                        where PE.Status<>0 
                        and PE.EntityType=15 
                        and Isnull(PE.OverallStatus, 0) =3
                        and PE.EntityID =@entityID
                        and PE.IntervalEndDate=(select max(IntervalEnddate) from  PrintEntity PE where PE.Status<>0 
                        and PE.EntityType=15 and Isnull(PE.OverallStatus ,0) > 0 and PE.EntityID =@entityID))

        if @flag > 0
        BEGIN
            set @statusCOunt=@statusCOunt+1
        END

set @counterID=@counterID+1
END
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `SELECT @statusCount`?

Comment: After your END just do Select @statusCount

Comment: Declare @statusCount as `OUTPUT`, and when you `return` from the procedure, you can get the data. Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: It worked. I am new to SQL scripting . Thank you all